# @replit/database db.get returning [object Object] on json

Tags: node.js, json, replit-database

I'm trying to use @replit/database for my backend, couldn't get it to display anything other than [object Object]

This is the code that I have

```
const Database = require("@replit/database")
const db = new Database()
app.get("/click", (req, res) => {
    num = db.get("num").then(value => {})
  res.send(JSON.stringify({num: num}))
});
```

Expected Output: A number that was previously saved
Output: [object object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xh2r.png)

Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Try `JSON.stringify({ "num": num })` or change the key to something else like number